# spark hive surrogate keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I do have a dataframe like below

```
+--------+-----+-------+-------------+----+
| movieID|Title|  genre|      row_key|TEST|
+--------+-----+-------+-------------+----+
|56053970|    3|6069358| PYME (otros)|   0|
|76076916|    9|7931718| PYME (otros)|   0|
| 9262542|    7|2572351| PYME (otros)|   0|
| 5356903|    K| 752733| PYME (otros)|   0|
| 5632710|    K| 852839|Independiente|   0|
|77725450|    2|5805474| PYME (otros)|   0|
+--------+-----+-------+-------------+----+
```

Now I my requirement is to add a column with increasing id say like surrogate keys in traditional RDBMS

now if I add the column with increasing id . Next time when I reload this Dataframe again  I need to increment and insert  getting the max id.

How can I achieve this ?

I have tried this in many ways .

But how can I achieve this?

Comment: you mean row_number?